# The best way to have a persistent object ready to use

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

maybe there are some similar questions like mine, but after searching for long time i couldn't find any!

I have an Object (OntologyHandler) filled with some rdf files that is used by an Activity and by a BroadcastReceiver. 
This OntologyHandler is really heavy to load, it doesn't matter when i start the Activity because i have a "Please Wait" message.

But the BroadcastReceiver is launched when there is an incoming call on the phone, so it must be as fast as possible to execute, and the 7/8 seconds needed to load the OntologyHandler object are really a lot of time.

So i want to load OntologyHandler just one time since i boot up the phone, and keep it fastly available for every access by the Activity or the BroadcastReceiver.

Can you tell me any suggestion, please?

--- EDIT ---

Actually, what I have is:

- The OntologyHandler:

  ```
  public class OntologyHandler {
      private static OntologyHandler instance;

      private OntologyHandler() {
          //loadOntology() is the method that spend a lot of time to terminate.
          loadOntology();
      }

      public synchronized static OntologyHandler getInstance()
      {
          if(instance == null)
          {
              instance = new OntologyHandler();
          }
          return instance;
      }

      public synchronized static void setInstance(OntologyHandler inst)
      {
          instance = inst;
      }

      public synchronized static boolean isInstanceLoaded()
      {
          return instance != null;
      }

      private void loadOntology()
      {
          //load the rdf files...
      }
  }
  ```
- The Service that loads the OntologyHandler for the first time, started by a BroadcastReceiver that listen on the `android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED` Intent:

  ```
  public class OntologyPreLoaderService extends IntentService {

      private OntologyHandler handler;

          public OntologyPreLoaderService() {
              super(OntologyPreLoaderService.class.getName());
          }

          @Override
          protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

          if (handler == null) {

              //I use a thread because the Process is executed in the main thread of the app, 
              //so, if the user starts the Activity he has no black screen while loading Ontology, 
              //but a "Please wait" message in an AlertDialog, dismissed when the Activity can access the 
              //OntologyHandler.getInstance(); synchronized static method
              new Thread() {
                  public void run() {
                      handler = OntologyHandler.getInstance();
                  }
              }.start();

          } else {
              OntologyHandler.setInstance(handler);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Both Activity and `PHONE_STATE` Intent BroadcastReceiver call this service to load the Ontology. 
The problem is that, after the SD Card is mounted (at phone boot time), `OntologyPreLoaderService` loads the Ontology correctly but, when finishing `onHandleIntent` method, the application process terminates, so when the Activity or phone BroadcastReceiver calls it, the `handler` field of the service is always null and the Service has to reload the Ontology again.

But I want that, once loading, the Service maintain the OntologyHandler instance, even if it ends its work and re-wake up again or something like.

Hope you understand me.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the part that loads the `OntologyHandler` as a `Service` that is launched when the phone boots, which will keep the data in memory for the other parts of your app to use when needed.

However, keeping a huge chunk of memory tied up like that is bound to cause problems. Can you re-evaluate your app and see if you can represent the data in the RDF files in another way, so they can be loaded in smaller portions as they are needed?

It would be helpful to understand what your app seeks to accomplish. Is the goal to display a patient's medical files when a specific patient calls the doctor's smartphone?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. What you wrote about Service is what I have now. See the --- EDIT --- paragraph i added to my Question. I can't dismiss RDF use because it is the central argument of this (University) project. The goal of this app/service is to let the user define the behavior of the phone (security policies) in certain contexts the user is in. For example, "when I'm during a work meeting (by phone calendar) and i receive a call by a friend (phone contact in group "Friends"), I automatically refuse the call/mute ringtone/send busy message ecc...". Hope you understand me. Greetings.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but there is no way these rules should require a file that is so big that it takes 8 seconds to load.

Comment: What should I say, man? The rdf files are 4, their load by the handler is, as I say, really heavy, maybe because the loader engine (called Androjena, a Apache Jena porting for Android) makes some semantic controls. But once the Ontology Model is created, the queries to it are fast. I was thinking to load the OntologyHandler instance and save it to a file (its load may be faster than the rdf loading, because it's a POJO and there is no need to do semantic controls), and delete every time the phone is shutted down, don't know what to do!

Comment: Can you convert the RDF data into a Sqlite database?

Comment: How much memory does the OntologyHandler consume once it is loaded?

Comment: Pass rdf data in sqlite db is not possible because the application is completed (except for this thing), and the queries have to be written in sparql (used by default in rdf). Don't know how much memory the OntologyHandler consumes, but not much (some kb)

Comment: If the memory consumption is reasonable, your approach of running a background service is fine. It looks like the permission rules need to be checked for virtually all phone activities, so this is a valid use of a service.

Comment: Yes but, as I wrote, once the Service terminates the method `onHandleIntent`, the process is destroyed and the loaded OntologyHandler instance is lost, so when i start the Activity or a call comes, the Activity or the BroadcastReceiver has to reload OntologyHandler again. So the Service is completely useless. I want to the Service wake up with the OntologyHandler instance loaded at phone boot.